# Template Debugging - I can't see it

Tags: templates, debugging

I've enabled template debugging on our EE installation on a test server. I can't see the template debugging information when I load pages (either in CPanel or templates). Another developer I work with can see them just fine on his machine. We're both logged in as Super Admin. Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: Just a thought, do you have any ad-block plugins running in your browser, also have you tried another browser?

Comment: Was using Chrome which did have an ad blocker. Turned it off, but nothing changed. Just tried it on IE and I now see template debugging. Must be something in my Chrome setting then?

Comment: does the source code view in Chrome show it? Are you definitely logged in as Super Admin in Chrome?

Comment: Kip - did you sort this out? Was it just an intermittent glitch?

Comment: No. I am definitely logged in as Super Admin. The source code does not have the debugging info. Not sure how ad blocker could affect this since it's not a popup (unlike, say, Smarty debugging). No problems in IE or FF, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have recently found that Chrome does not display the debugging information if the developer tools are being used.

I do not have any idea why this happens, but whenever I am logged in and not seeing the debugging info, it is because the developer tools are open.

I am using Chrome v23.0.1271.101, and EE 2.5.3

Comment: That solved it! That's the strangest thing ever. Thanks.